# How can I label Pandas DataFrames columns and rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a data frame like this:

[image: Table]

This is what I have so far:

```
labels = ['Rain', 'No Rain']
pd.DataFrame([[27, 63],[7, 268]], columns=labels, index=labels)
```

That looks like this:

[image]

But that doesn't create the parent categories. How can I label the columns as "Actual Weather" and the rows as "Forecast"?

Comment: you can try creating a multiindex with index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples) with the tuples being (("Actual Weather","Rain"),("Actual Weather","No Rain")) and the same for the row index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a multi-index for the index and the columns:

```
In [17]:
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[27,63],[7,268]], columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Actual Weather','Rain'),('Actual Weather', 'No Rain')]),
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Forecast','Rain'),('Forecast','No Rain')]))
df

Out[17]:
                 Actual Weather        
                           Rain No Rain
Forecast Rain                27      63
         No Rain              7     268
```

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the names of the columns and index axes, you can set `.name` property on those:

```py
>>> labels = ['Rain', 'No Rain']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[27, 63],[7, 268]], columns=labels, index=labels)
>>> df.columns.name = 'Actual Weather'
>>> df.index.name = 'Forecast'
>>> print(df)
Actual Weather  Rain  No Rain
Forecast                     
Rain              27       63
No Rain            7      268
```